# railsでfindするときにhas_many側をlimitできますか。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

以下のようなモデルがあったとして

```rb
class Post
  has_many :histories
end

class History
  belongs_to :post
end
```

以下の様なイメージでfindするときに一時的にhasMany側のlimitを変更することはできますか。

```rb
Post.find(1).histories.limit(5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ご質問の場合、.limit() は Post（Posts?）の取得件数となります。
取得する件数が固定であれば、histories のアソシエーションで行けるのではないかと。

https://railsguides.jp/association_basics.html#has-many%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6-limit

動的にやる方法は分かりかねます。

Comment: 取得条件は分かっているでしょうから、動的にやるなら、個別に取得すればよいですね。